# How to check if SQL server query is pulling query results from cache

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

if I run one complicated SQL query it finishes in two minutes. If I run it again it finishes in 30 seconds. So I guess SQL Server has cached something.

Can I check somehow if the query result that I am getting is pulled from some cache or not?

Comment: Do you mean "Cached"? The first time a query is run, SQL Server will need to generate a query plan. if you run it again, it won't need to, as it has been cached. The data, however, is never cached *(As Jeroen points out, data is possibly the wrong word, and Results is a better one)*. if you want to (for some reason) always generate the plan, use `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`, but you should only use that if you have good reason to need to recreate the plan each time the query is run 9for example, if you have a Catch All Query).

Comment: SQL Server never caches query *results*, but it does cache data pages read from disk in the buffer pool. If you run another query that uses the same data, it too will be sped up. If you want to see if the query hit the disk or not, use `SET STATISTICS IO ON` and pay attention to the physical reads. On a test machine (and only there!) you can use `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS` to clear the buffer pool and force all subsequent reads to come from disk.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for your answers! You cleared up this for me. Also, I corrected spelling :).

Comment: The real question should be how to make the query faster, not whether a database server caches data - that's what databases *always* do. Even 30 seconds sounds too much. Does the query use indexes efficiently? Are you running a reporting query on top of an OLTP database? Using the proper indexes and/or proper schema can return data in milliseconds from hundreds of thousands of rows

Answer (score 0):

It is a normal condition. SQL Server placed the required data in its cache from the last query execution. So, no more read is needed next time the query is being executed. If there is an error in execution, it shows that on the output window.

Comment: As a simple solution, You can see actual query execution plan to see if all parts of your query was executed.